# Android Studio desgn mode for fullscreen app

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using AS 2.3.3 with a full screen app. I know how to put the app into full screen at run time but the design view still shows the status bar, a title and the nav buttons. How can I remove those from the preview so it looks as it will be when deployed?

Comment: select apptheme.noactionbar in preview

Comment: Select theme Material.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen in your preview window of Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AS design view click the little round violet icon that says **Theme**. *Select Theme* dialog will pop up. Type "fullscreen" into the search bar and choose the full screen theme that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add NoActionBar theme to your application as:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

and set theme in style.xml as:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Open the Preview panel and click on Theme in Editor as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

> After clicking on that you can see this dialog and you can choose your
>   own theme for preview.

[image]